# How to hide the metadata of the article (about us)? (Joomla 3.7.3)

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I'm trying to hide the date of publication of the article and anoter metadata.The visibility of these metadata on the "about us" page is rather unacceptable. Removing this from the template will not solve the problem, because in other places I need to have information about it.
Maybe someone knows another way to create a site about us?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLWHp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have to hide it in "about us" menu item too